# scikit-learn の train_test_split でエラー: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Tags: python, 機械学習, google-colaboratory, scikit-learn

Python初心者で機械学習を使用した疫学研究をしていますが進め方が合っているかどうかもわからないです。現在、ハイパーパラメータ調整で躓いています。もしよければアドバイス、指摘をお願いします。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv
csvfile = open('BioAsseT practice data5.csv')
df = pd.read_csv("BioAsseT practice data5.csv")
X=df.external
y=df.total
X.shape, y.shape
((103,), (103,))
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train_val, X_test, y_train_val, y_test=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, y_test=train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-3f9989894ee6> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_val,  y_train, y_val, y_test=train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```py
> X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, y_test=train_test_split(X_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
> ```

上記は左辺の変数が1つ余分です。4つにしましょう。

Comment: 指摘・編集ありがとうございます。修正できました。